# AWSのIoT経由でメール（mosquitto_pub）

Tags: python

ラズパイのGPIO（16）でスイッチONの時に
AWSのIoT経由でメールを飛ばそうと考えているのですが、
下のPythonプログラムの `mosquitto_pub ~` の行で「SyntaxError: invalid syntax」が出ます。
初歩的なコトかも知れませんが、不具合箇所をご指摘いただきたく、よろしくお願いします。
ちなみに、ラズパイで直接コマンド入力で、同一文（`mosquitto_pub　・・・・・　-m 'Hello, World'`）を入力すると正常にメール送信されます。

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

# モジュールをインポートする
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# GPIO指定をGPIO番号で行う
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# GPIO16ピンを入力モードに設定
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN)

num = 0
while num < 10:
    print (GPIO.input(16))  # GPIO16ピンの入力状態を表示する
    if GPIO.input(16) == 1 :
        mosquitto_pub --cafile rootCA.pem --cert ～～～～～～～-certificate.pem.crt --key ～～～～～～～-private.pem.key -h ～～～～～～～.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t topic/sns -m 'Hello, World'
    num = num +1
    time.sleep(1)
print ("End")

# GPIOピンをリセット
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python のプログラムと、シェルに打ち込む[コマンド](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89_(%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF))とを混同なさっています。

```sh
mosquitto_pub --cafile rootCA.pem --cert ～～～～～～～-certificate.pem.crt --key ～～～～～～～-private.pem.key -h ～～～～～～～.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t topic/sns -m 'Hello, World'
```

というのは `mosquitto_pub` という実行ファイルに `--cafile rootCA.pem` など様々なオプション引数をつけた上で実行するという、シェルのコマンドです。これをそのまま Python のプログラムとして打ち込んでも上手く動きません。

外部実行ファイルを Python から動かすためには、たとえば標準ライブラリの [subprocess モジュール](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/subprocess.html)が使えます。以下は Python 3.5 以降で可能な書き方です。

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["mosquitto_pub", "--cafile", "rootCA.pem", （省略）])
```

バージョン 3.5 より古い Python では、[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.jp/3.4/library/subprocess.html)を使う方法があります。

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call("mosquitto_pub", "--cafile", "rootCA.pem", （省略）])
```